# How to split non-delimited email-addresses?

Tags: delphi

I have a txt file that contains a large quantity of emails and they are delimited with no space. And I want organize these emails line by line.

So, my question is: how get  only the part that separates these emails?

*Ex:* (foo.txt)

**brarabelalima@hotmail.comaracaesporteclube@terra.com.br**

*And I want like this:* (new.txt)

**brarabelalima@hotmail.com**

**aracaesporteclube@terra.com.br**

This was my last attempt:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  Classes;

procedure arrumarEmailsTXT;
var
 Linhas, Colunas:TStringList;
 i,j:integer;
 arq: TextFile;
begin
 Linhas := TStringList.Create;
 Colunas := TStringList.Create;
 AssignFile(arq, 'new.txt');
 Rewrite(arq);
 try
   Linhas.LoadFromFile('foo.txt');
   for i := 0 to Pred(Linhas.Count) do
   begin
     Colunas.text := StringReplace(Linhas.Strings[i],'',#13,[rfReplaceAll]);
     for j := 0 to Pred(Colunas.Count) do
     begin
      Writeln(arq, Colunas.Strings[j]);
     end;
   end;
 finally
   CloseFile(arq);
   Linhas.Free;
   Colunas.Free;
 end;
end;

begin
  arrumarEmailsTXT;
end.
```

Comment: You need to find a set of rules to determine where one address ends and another one starts.

Comment: Not enough information. Are they all .com addresses? Are they all simple TLDs? Are there multiple periods after the `@`, like `fred.smith@somewhere.mysite.com`? What about any special characters in the name portion, like `&` or `(`? Be more specific, and define the exact rules you want to use to define the start and end of an email address. Your current attempt clearly won't work, because you're attempting to replace an empty space (`''`) with a carriage return, and there can't possibly be any empty spaces in your text file. Define your rules for an email address.

Comment: Also, I've removed the `delimited` tag, because if the file were delimited there wouldn't be an issue, but according to your own words and example there is no delimiter.

Comment: Arbitrary example: `me@infour@in` Is the first domain `.info` or India `.in`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

***SOLUTION:***

```
 {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

    {$R *.res}

    uses
      Winapi.Windows,
      Classes,
      System.SysUtils;

    function ExtractEmails(const Input: String; out Emails: TStringList): Boolean;
    var
      I : Integer;
      Buffer : String;
      Tokens : TStringList;
    begin
      Result := False;
      Tokens := TStringList.Create;
      Emails := TStringList.Create;
      Try
        Tokens.Delimiter := #32;
        Tokens.DelimitedText := Input;
        For I := 0 To Tokens.Count - 1 Do
          begin
          Buffer := Tokens.Strings[I];
          If Length(Buffer) < 5 Then Continue;
          If (Pos('@',Buffer) > 1) And
             (Pos('.',Buffer) > 3) And
             (Pos('.',Buffer) < Length(Buffer)) Then
             begin
             Emails.Add(Buffer);
          end;
        end;
        Result := True;
      Finally
        Tokens.Free;
      end;
    end;

    procedure Extrai;
     var
     Linhas,Emails:TStringList;
     arq: TextFile;
    begin
     Linhas := TStringList.Create;
     Emails := TStringList.Create;
     try
       Linhas.LoadFromFile('foo.txt');
       AssignFile(arq, 'emails.txt');
       Rewrite(arq);
          If ExtractEmails(Linhas.Text,Emails) Then
           begin
            Writeln(arq,Emails.Text);
           end;
     finally
       CloseFile(arq);
       Linhas.Free;
       Emails.Free;
     end;
    end;

    begin
       Extrai;
    end.
```

Comment: Code without explanation?

Comment: If your are using TStringLists in `ExtractEmails`, why on Earth are you using AssignFile, Rewrite, etc to save the output?

Comment: @MartynA, to save the output in  new txt file.

Comment: Well, TStringList has a SaveToFile method as well as a LoadFromFile one, and you're already using the latter.  Once Emails has what you want in it,  just call its SaveToFile.

Comment: This can not be the solution because you are tokenizing the input with `#32` (space) as the delimiter, but by your own statement and your example there are no spaces between the email addresses. Further the handling of the `Buffer` seems to be grabbed out of blue.

Comment: This code is just so wrong it's hard to decide where to start trying to help. Instead of posting this extremely sad, poor hack of an attempt to solve the problem, you should edit your question to make it more clear what your requirements are (as has been asked before) and let someone help you who at least has an idea about what they're doing,.

Answer (score -3):

First run through the text and create a list with the parts between the @-@

Then, take each entry of the new list and cut the text up from the beginning up to the first period. This will give you a list of the domains those emails have.

Then, you need to fill in the last part of the domains and create a new list base don your experience.
For example, for every 'hotmail' you will have 'hotmail.com' and 'hotmail.co.uk', etc.

After that, you can extract the correct position for each line based on the full domain names.

This however can become very heavy job and take much time and resources. Is your file big? You may need threads to run the job effectively.

Also, knowledge of where the emails come may help you cut down the domains.

Comment: What about the totally valid address `fred.smith@somewhere.mysite.com`? What about those with only two letter domains, like `.ru` or `.sp`? What about the perfectly legal addresses that contain special characters like `&` or `(`?

Comment: @Ken what about them? That's his problem---he doesn't know the domains (or the usernames). You ask him to define rules the moment he doesn't have predefined rules.

Comment: No, that's something your incomplete answer doesn't address, which are extremely real possibilities. Instead, you ramble off on some nonsense about a *very heavy job* and *threads*. Instead of posting an answer to a question that is incomplete in its details, you should wait for clarification of the requirements. Posting an inadequate or incomplete answer is no better than posting a wrong answer. *cut the text up from the beginning up to the first period* does **not** give you a list of the domains (as my `fred.smith` example demonstrates).

Comment: @Ken, ok...if he has 100K lines in the text file that for loop will crash the app. But anyway, this is not the point of the question. If I offered nonsense, then your question just take up space as you only ask what he doesn't know. That's why he needs ideas how to get the emails. If he had the answers to your questions, he would be capable to use the replace function. Anyway, let's wait for the author

Comment: You have no information that suggests that, any more than you have information regarding the types of email addresses that are in the file. The point of the question is that the user is asking for help resolving a problem that has not yet been fully defined, and speculating on possible solutions to that unspecified problem are not beneficial. Yes, what you should have done in the first place is *wait for the author*, rather than writing your post. And *What about them? That's his problem* is the entire point - it's his problem, and it needs to be defined before we can help solve it.